# Can't find a control from EditItemTemplate in a Dynamic GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a dynamic GridView :

```
public class DynamicGridView
{
public DynamicGridView(SectiuneFormular sectiuneFormular , int idFormular)
{
    this.idFormular = idFormular;
    gridView = new GridView();
    sectiune = sectiuneFormular;
    dataTable = new DataTable();
    gridView.DataSource = dataTable;
    SeteazaDataTable();
    SeteazaAspectGridView();
    gridView.DataBind();

}

private int idFormular = 0;
public int IdFormular
{
    get
    {
        return idFormular;
    }

    set
    {
        idFormular = value;
    }
}

private GridView gridView;
public GridView GridView
{
    get
    {
        return gridView;
    }

    set
    {
        gridView = value;
    }
}

private SectiuneFormular sectiune;
public SectiuneFormular Sectiune
{
    get
    {
        return sectiune;
    }

    set
    {
        sectiune = value;
    }
}

private DataTable dataTable;
public DataTable DataTable
{
    get
    {
        return dataTable;
    }

    set
    {
        dataTable = value;
    }
}


public void SeteazaDataTable()
{
    //Adaug Header si denumirea lui
    for (int numarColoana = 2; numarColoana <= 15; numarColoana++)
    {
        if (sectiune.Sablon.Coloane[numarColoana] != "")
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(sectiune.Sablon.Coloane[numarColoana]);
            AdaugaColoanaGridView(sectiune.Sablon.Coloane[numarColoana] , numarColoana);
        }
    }
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Id");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("IdFormular");

    //Incarc datele in tabel
    int numarColoane = dataTable.Columns.Count;
    foreach (Inregistrare continut in sectiune.Continut)
    {
        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        for (int coloana = 0; coloana < numarColoane-2; coloana++)
        {
            dataRow[coloana] = continut.Coloane[coloana+2]; 

        }
        dataRow[numarColoane-1] = continut.Id;
        dataRow[numarColoane - 2] = idFormular;
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

}


public void SeteazaAspectGridView()
{

    gridView.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = true;
    gridView.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;

    gridView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "Id" , "IdFormular" };

    gridView.AllowPaging = true;
    gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    gridView.Width = new Unit("75%");
    gridView.EmptyDataText = "Nu s-au gasit inregistrari";
    gridView.CellPadding = 4;
    gridView.CssClass = "GridView";
    gridView.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#33333");
    gridView.GridLines = GridLines.None;
    gridView.EnableModelValidation = true;
    gridView.RowStyle.CssClass = "GridViewItem";
    gridView.FooterStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0099FF");
    gridView.PagerStyle.CssClass = "GridViewPager";
    gridView.PagerStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0099FF");
    gridView.PagerStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    gridView.SelectedRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D1DDF1");
    gridView.SelectedRowStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#333333");
    gridView.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "GridViewHeader";
    gridView.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2084C5");
    gridView.HeaderStyle.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    gridView.EditRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2461BF");
    gridView.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "GridViewItem";
}



public void AdaugaColoanaGridView(string dataField , int numarColoana)
{
    TemplateField tf2 = new TemplateField();
    tf2.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.Header, dataField, dataField, new Label() , numarColoana , "header");
    tf2.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, dataField, dataField, new Label() , numarColoana  , "item");
    tf2.EditItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, dataField, dataField, new TextBox() , numarColoana ,"edit");

    //BoundField numeColoana = new BoundField();
    //numeColoana.DataField = dataField;
    //numeColoana.HeaderText = dataField;


    //gridView.Columns.Add(numeColoana);
    gridView.Columns.Add(tf2);
}



}
```

.

```
 public class GridViewTemplate : ITemplate
{
private DataControlRowType templateType;
private string columnNameFriendly;
private string columnNameData;
private Control control;
private int numarColoana;
private string type;
public GridViewTemplate(DataControlRowType type, string colNameFr, string colNameDt, Control con , int numarColoana , string tip)
{
    templateType = type;
    columnNameFriendly = colNameFr;
    columnNameData = colNameDt;
    control = con;
    this.numarColoana = numarColoana;
    this.type = tip;
}

public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
{
    switch (templateType)
    {
        case DataControlRowType.Header:
            {
                Literal lc = new Literal();
                lc.Text = columnNameFriendly;
                container.Controls.Add(lc);
                break;
            }
        case DataControlRowType.DataRow:
            {
                Control field = control;
                if (field.GetType() == typeof(Label))
                {
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.ID = "label"+type+ numarColoana;
                    lbl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.lbl_DataBind);
                    container.Controls.Add(lbl);
                }
                else if (field.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                {

                    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.ID = "textbox"+type+ numarColoana;
                    txt.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.txt_DataBind);
                    container.Controls.Add(txt);
                }
                else if (field.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
                {
                    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)field;
                    ddl.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.ddl_DataBind);
                    container.Controls.Add(ddl);
                }
                else if (field.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
                {
                    CheckBox cbx = new CheckBox();
                    cbx.DataBinding += new EventHandler(this.cbx_DataBind);
                    container.Controls.Add(cbx);
                }
                break;
            }
    }
}

private void txt_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)txt.NamingContainer;
    txt.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, columnNameData).ToString();
    txt.Font.Name = "Arial";
}

private void lbl_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lbl.NamingContainer;
    lbl.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, columnNameData).ToString();
    lbl.Font.Name = "Arial";
}

private void ddl_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
    ddl.SelectedValue = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, columnNameData).ToString();
    ddl.Font.Name = "Arial";
}

private void cbx_DataBind(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)cbx.NamingContainer;
    cbx.Checked = false;
}
}
```

1.First issue :
my event for RowUpdating is handled by    *GridViewEditEventHandler* , but not by GridViewUpdateEventHandler (tested breakpoint).

2. if i press Update Cell

   ```
     string cell=  grid.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[cellNumber].Controls[0].ToString(); //cell== OldItemValue(from my ViewItemTemplate)
   ```

cell== "OldItemValue" , from my ViewItemTemplate , but it must retrieves its value from EditItemTemplate

Answer (score 0):

When you press whatever button that does "Edit" command, RowEditing event should happen. After that, pressing "Update" fires the RowUpdating command. In the RowEditing handler, thats where you'd find the control and get its value. You're doing

`string cell=grid.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[cellNumber].Controls[0].ToString();`

... I usually do `grid.rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ID OF CONTROL")` to get the exact control.

Question is a little confusing so I might not have given you the answer. Could you provide more information?